Capture packets with a raw AF_INET socket on Linux Python 3
So I have a raw IP socket in python created as follows:
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_RAW)

I have bound it to an interface using the following:
SO_BINDTODEVICE = 25
interface = "enp3s0f1"
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, SO_BINDTODEVICE, interface.encode("utf-8"))
s.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_HDRINCL, 1) # I am wrapping my own IP headers for testing purposes

I can wrap my own IPv4 packets with a couple of custom protocols and send them out the socket using the following:
s.sendto(packet_data, (dest_ip_address, 0)) #This will do the ethernet framing for me

However, when I try to receive a custom protocol packet on the raw socket using the following:
recv_data = s.recvfrom(65535)

I fail to capture anything. On wireshark, I can see the packet getting to the linux system, but the system is responding with an "ICMP: Protocol Unreachable" response message.
How might I go about receiving a custom IPv4 packet? Can I still receive multiple custom protocols on the same socket? I only want the data from a single interface.

Wireshark uses the BPF API, which allows capturing packets before they're processed by the TCP/IP stack. Why are you doing this with raw sockets instead of a library like scapy?

I chose raw sockets because I wanted to challenge myself and figure out how to do some low-level networking, while at the same time having the ease of python.
